# Windows XP, having to add Everyone each time for each file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing

In the last few months I've had to make some changes to file sharing on our home LAN. We now have a Windows 7 laptop and a Mac Mini and I had to move away from simple file sharing.

I find myself now, when I create a shared folder that I have to add the "Everyone" user and give it full control to allow other computers to access my files and vice versa. We have other XP machines too.

My problem is that if someone creates a file in a shared folder I then have to add "Everyone" for each file, even if the shared folder is on my PC and my wife creates the file on my PC from her laptop. I can't access it on my PC even though the file is on my computer.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the "advanced" window in the security tab of the folder and tried checking the two checkboxes, adding "everyone" to the folder in the process?

Comment: Erm, not sure, I've just had a look in there and I cant see that option

Comment: I mean I didn't d that when i setup up the folder and I can't see that option now.

Comment: http://sadpanda.us/images/234754-9HWA7FC.png , it's the two down there. Sorry for German interface

Comment: Do you have "Simple File Sharing" (**Tools > Folder Options... > View** then scroll down to the bottom of the advanced settings list box) enabled?

Comment: @ChrisF Oh, I forgot he could have that activated still...

Comment: No I don't have simple file sharing enabled, my screens are different, I've done some screen shots of all the tabs http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/fece062e-9b03-43c1-9b48-e3842896e4f0/2010-10-05_1010.png http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/e50e80f0-4110-430b-842c-7c645141ecfd/2010-10-05_1011.png http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/33221f0d-01bd-4542-be79-1762daf6d07a/2010-10-05_1013.png

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/b4910c38-b9fe-4c67-83cc-cf56e9f1ed65/2010-10-05_1014.png

Comment: For completness heres the sharing setting too http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/5cec7a60-42bb-4cd9-8f0a-0d11f4eb25c3/2010-10-05_1017.png

Comment: Try the replacing thing though. Maybe the inheriting will work afterwards

Comment: replacing thing ?

Comment: "Replace permission entries on all child objects..." while putting "everyone" into the list on top. It's on your first screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The default permission when sharing a folder from Windows Vista or Windows 7, depends on whether you have enabled password-protected file sharing. If password-protected file sharing is not enabled, everyone is granted "Full Control" permission to the files in the shared folder. If password-protected file sharing is enabled, you must add the users or groups you want to grant access to.

In Network and Sharing Center window, Change advanced sharing settings, you should turn **off** password protected sharing (details [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/125876-password-protected-sharing-turn-off.html)). My only problem, not having Win7, is the fact that when password protected sharing is off, you only enable simple file sharing. But try it and see.

Comment: It happens with XP too

Comment: Do you have a password on Guest? And why can't you go back to Simple File Sharing (which is the simplest solution) ?